# Number of permutations with cycle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am asked to find how many permutations of the set $\{1, \dots, 10\}$ are there taking into account that there must be a $4$-cycle with the numbers $1,2,3,4$.

My attempt is the following: there are $3!$ different $4$-cycles within $\{1, \dots, 4\}$. Then, the only problem would be the remaining numbers. Thus we need to find how many ways are there to permute them, being this independent to the $4$-cycle, and there are $6!$ ways.

Therefore, there are $3!6!$ possible permutations satisfying these conditions.

Comment: I agree._______

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite right. There are $4!$ different permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. In addition, you haven't taken into account the fact that the $4$-cycle could occur anywhere in the permutation. The are $7$ positions for the $4$-cycle, so the total number of permutations is $7*4!6!$.

Another way of thinking about this is that $6$ elements outside of the $4$-cycle and the $4$-cycle itself make up $7$ things that can be permuted, giving us $4!7!$. In either case, that's $120960$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The OP specified "a $4$-cycle *with the numbers $1,2,3,4$*", so his solution was the right one.